# How to export imported object in ES6?

Tags: import, export, ecmascript-6

The use case is simple: I just want to export an object with the name just as it was imported.

for example:

```
import React from 'react';
export React;
```

but this does not work. I have to write:

```
import React from 'react';
export const React = React;
```

But this is odd. What is the right way to do this?

**UPDATED**:

Thanks for helps and references. I have solved out my problem with many clues. I'd like to share some common cases for me and the solutions.

#### export imports

```
import d, {obj} from '...';

export {obj, d};
export {obj as name1, d as name2};
```

#### re-export all named imports

```
export * from '...';
export * as name1 from '...';
```

#### re-export some named imports

```
export {a, b as name1} from '...';
```

#### re-export default import as default export

```
export {default} from '...';
```

#### re-export default import as named export

```
export {default as name1} from '...';
```

Comment: why would you export react?

Comment: you can `export {React}` but again, if you need React somewhere, you should just import it there.

Comment: export react is just an example, in fact, I want organize some project so that user can import some object in shorter and high level path.

Comment: Thank you so much for that update. It solved every problem I had with ES6/7. I suggest you to add this as an answer and accept it.

Comment: `export * as name1 from '...';` this doesnt work for me (using webpack 2). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you easily re-export aliases for default? Or is this necessary:

`export { default as name1, default as name2 } from '...';`

Comment: @AlexSashaRegan try `export {default} from '...';`

Comment: Does anyone have a workaround for `export * as name1 from '...';`?

Answer (score 179):

I often do the following in index.js files that compose several files:

```
export {default as SomeClass} from './SomeClass';
export {someFunction} from './utils';
export {default as React} from 'react';
```

This [blog entry](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) provides some nice additional examples.

#### Important note

You should be aware this [eslint-rule](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-named-as-default-member.md) when accessing these exported imports. Basically, in another file, you shouldn't:

```
import SomeClassModule from 'SomeClass/index.js';
SomeClassModule.someFunction(); // Oops, error
```

You should do this:

```
import SomeClassModule, {someFunction} from 'SomeClass/index.js';
someFunction(); // Ok
```

Answer (score 57):

You could export imported file with such structure

```
import First from './First'
import Second from './Second'
/..../
export { First, Second }
```

Answer (score 1):

For my use case, I explicitly need some sort of explicit import statement so that babel can transpile my es7 code to es5.

The following results in an error `You gave us a visitor for the node type "ForAwaitStatement" but it's not a valid type`:

```
require( 'babel-core/register' ); //transpiles es7 to es5
export {default} from './module_name'
```

My solution was to explicitly import the module by using `require()`:

```
require( 'babel-core/register' );
export default require( './module_name' ).default;
```

Answer (score -2):

Given `./foo.js`:

```
const Foo = class {
  talk() { return 'hello'; }
};

export default Foo;
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
import Foo from './foo';

let foo = new Foo();

foo.talk(); // => 'hello';
```

The syntax more or less follows the commonjs module.exports pattern, where you would do this:

```
const Foo = class {

};

module.exports = Foo;
```

More here:

http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: That's not quite what the question was about?