# Difference between: "export { something }" vs "export something"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

What is the difference between doing the following:

```
import something from "../something";
export { something };
```

vs

```
import something from "../something";
export something;
```

In [react-is](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-is) package from react, there is an export doing that same thing. I want to understand what that means.

Here is the line of code that does it. https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-is/src/ReactIs.js#L69

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200080/how-to-export-imported-object-in-es6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export imported object in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200080/how-to-export-imported-object-in-es6)

Comment: One exports `something` while the other exports an Object with `something` on it.

Comment: @zero298 how would you import the one that does `export { something }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first snippet is correct. It imports default export from `../something` and exports it as `something` named export from current module.

ES module [`export` has limited syntax variations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export), so does `import`. If the syntax isn't listed in the reference, it's not supported.

```
export something;
```

isn't valid, it will result in syntax error. `something` is an expression in `export something`. According to the reference, only `export default` can use an expression.

Named exports should either contain a declaration:

```
export let something = ...;
```

Or if `something` already exists in current scope, like in this case, braces should be used:

```
export { something };
```

If `something` isn't used in current module for anything but re-export, a shortcut for

```
import something from "../something";
export { something };
```

is

```
export { default as something } from "../something";
```